# Big O if 2^n vs. 4^n

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

I'm trying to figure out these two Big O's. Obviously the big O of 2^n is O(2^n), but I'm not sure if you can reduce 4^n. If so, I would do 4^n = (2^2)^n. Then we could distribute to make this 2^(2n), which I would reduce to O(2^n) since the constant in front of the n wouldn't matter.

Is this correct? Thank you.

Comment: No, it's not correct: there's no constant C such that `4^n <= C 2^n` for all sufficiently large `n`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia on Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):

> On the other hand, exponentials with different bases are not of the same order. For example, 2^n and 3^n are not of the same order.

Answer (score 21):

Let's try to arrive at this for ourselves. Assume 4^n = O(2^n). Then there is some m and some c such that 4^n <= c*2^n for all n >= m. Then we have for all n >= m:

```
   (2*2)^n <= c*2^n
=> 2^n * 2^n <= c*2^n
=> c >= 2^n
```

So c can clearly not be constant, a contradiction.

Comment: nice. better than just quoting wikipedia :)

Comment: This is a great comment, very instructive (and agree, much better than a quote that just says they aren't the same order). This employs the product rule of exponents: a^n * b^n = (a * b)^n and a proof by contradiction.